# Variable contents from a file disappears and loop doesnt enter

Tags: php, foreach, fwrite, fgets

I have the following code to read from a file, and write back to it after some computation.

```
    if(file_exists(CACHE_FILE_PATH)) {
        //read the cache and delete that line!
        $inp = array();
        $cache = fopen(CACHE_FILE_PATH, 'r');
        if($cache) {
            while(!feof($cache)) {
                $tmp = fgets($cache);
                //some logic with $tmp
                    $inp[] = $tmp;
            }

            fclose($cache);
        }

        var_dump($inp);

        $cache = fopen(CACHE_FILE_PATH, 'w');

        var_dump($inp);
        if($cache) {

            var_dump($inp);

            foreach ($inp as $val) {
                echo "\nIN THE LOOP";
                fwrite($val."\n");
            }

            fclose($cache);
        }   
    }
```

The output of the var_dumps is:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "bedupako|714
"
  [1]=>
  string(16) "newBedupako|624
"
  [2]=>
  string(19) "radioExtension|128
"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "bedupako|714
"
  [1]=>
  string(16) "newBedupako|624
"
  [2]=>
  string(19) "radioExtension|128
"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "bedupako|714
"
  [1]=>
  string(16) "newBedupako|624
"
  [2]=>
  string(19) "radioExtension|128
"
}
```

Even though its an array, it is not going in the loop and printing `IN THE LOOP`! Why?

Comment: `$cache` probably doesn't evaluate to `true`. You have 3 `var_dump()` calls in different places so it's impossible to tell which parts of the code are executed.

Comment: Surprised `fwrite($val."\n");` isn't complaining here since the first param is meant to be the file resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part of your code:

```
fwrite($val."\n");
```

Should be:

```
fwrite($cache, $val); // the "\n" is only required if it was stripped off after fgets()
```

The first argument to `fwrite()` must be a file descriptor opened with `fopen()`.

Of course, if you had turned on `error_reporting(-1)` and `ini_set('display_errors', 'On')` during development you would have spotted this immediately :)

As suggested in the comments, you should try to simplify your code by using constructs like `file()` to read the whole file into an array of lines and then use `join()` and `file_put_contents()` to write the whole thing back.

If you just want a cache of key/value pairs, you could look into something like this:

```
// to read, assuming the cache file exists
$cache = include CACHE_FILE_PATH;

// write back cache
file_put_contents(CACHE_FILE_PATH, '<?php return ' . var_export($cache, true) . ';');
```

It reads and writes files containing data structures that PHP itself can read (a lot faster than you can).

Comment: But the answer is pretty limited. You should first of all take a look into the high-level file-functions of PHP. For example you can use a PHP file or a INI file to create easily accessible key-value file-based storage. Keep your code small, then you do not have that many places where you can do silly mistakes. `$inp = file(CACHE_FILE_PATH);` and for writing use implode, it's outlined as well on http://php.net/file - also see http://php.net/var_export

Comment: @hakre Fair enough, added an example of an alternative.

Comment: @Jack: That's a fine example.